# Why is my aloe tipping over?

Tags: succulents, aloe, repotting

My aloe has tipped over and I'm not sure what to do with it. Should I leave it leaning? If not I could try to repot it but the middle stem is so bent that I'm not sure how to have it stand vertically.

Edit: The aloe grew like this naturally, it wasn't damaged by anything.

Any tips or ideas appreciated.

[image: leaning aloe]

Comment: can you please clarify whether your plant has simply grown naturally in this way over time, or whether it has collapsed from damage of some sort near the base?

Comment: most likely cause is being grown under light levels that are too low

Comment: Kevinsky >> that might be it.. It's the only room that the cats don't bother it in. Should I start rotating it?

Comment: How much are you watering it, because the plant looks dehydrated, but I can't tell for sure even though the plant looks like inside is curved in, not curved out?

Answer (score 4):

If it's been in that position for a long time, with any light always coming from the same direction, that would explain this. It should have been rotated regularly, say bi weekly or monthly, but the only thing you can do now is to turn it so that all the growth is pointing away from the window, and leave it in that position for some months. It may, or may not, persuade the existing growth to change position, but I have to say that isn't terribly likely, so keep an eye on how it's growing - if it doesn't become more upright, but new growth starts reaching for the window, you'll have to turn it regularly to keep that upright and not worry about the bent growth you've already got.

Over time, with new growth, you may want to consider cutting out this bent growth, but see how it goes.

Comment: It needs more light and less water. Under low light if it's watered carefully, the growth can be slow enough that the stem is strong, not elongated. [Here is a picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MU2TO.jpg) of one of mine, showing very little space between leaves (watered very little, grown in less than ideal light)